# Help understand Moore Penrose inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook first define Moore Penrose inverse using singular value decomposition.

> [image]

If I am right, we should have

> ${{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}} = {\mathbf{V}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   {{{\mathbf{\sigma }}^{ - 1}}}&{\mathbf{O}} \\ 
>   {\mathbf{O}}&{\mathbf{O}} 
> \end{array}} \right){{\mathbf{U}}^*}{\mathbf{U}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   {\mathbf{\Sigma }}&{\mathbf{O}} \\ 
>   {\mathbf{O}}&{\mathbf{O}} 
> \end{array}} \right){{\mathbf{V}}^*} = {{\mathbf{I}}_{n \times n}}$
>
> ${\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + } = {\mathbf{U}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   {\mathbf{\sigma }}&{\mathbf{O}} \\ 
>   {\mathbf{O}}&{\mathbf{O}} 
> \end{array}} \right){{\mathbf{V}}^*}{\mathbf{V}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   {{{\mathbf{\sigma }}^{ - 1}}}&{\mathbf{O}} \\ 
>   {\mathbf{O}}&{\mathbf{O}} 
> \end{array}} \right){{\mathbf{U}}^*} = {{\mathbf{I}}_{m \times m}}$

What now puzzles me is the following statement

> [image]

The textbook further say above is actually a better definition for the pseudoinverse.

**My question is**: why we cannot say that for a $m \times n$ matrix $\bf A$, ${\bf A}_0$ is its pseudoinverse if ${\bf A}{\bf A}_0={\bf I}_{m\times m}$ and ${\bf A}_0{\bf A}={\bf I}_{n\times n}$, but instead using much more complicated conditions as above?

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix from $n$ to $m$ dimensional space, where $n > m$, then there *can't* be a matrix $B$ such that $BA=I_{n}$, because $A$ isn't injective.

Comment: The two equations you give in the middle are wrong. You DON'T have ${{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}} = {\mathbf{V}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{{\mathbf{\sigma }}^{ - 1}}}&{\mathbf{O}} \\ 
  {\mathbf{O}}&{\mathbf{O}} 
\end{array}} \right){{\mathbf{U}}^*}{\mathbf{U}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\mathbf{\Sigma }}&{\mathbf{O}} \\ 
  {\mathbf{O}}&{\mathbf{O}} 
\end{array}} \right){{\mathbf{V}}^*} = {{\mathbf{I}}_{n \times n}}$ and the other.